# Material UI and Next.js - dynamic styles not working

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui, next.js

I am using Next JS with Material UI, and I set up the project using the example from the docs on Github: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs

My goal is to use Material UI's styling solution to create custom theme. I want to use custom theme colors like "red", "green", "blue", "yellow, on top of the existing "primary" and "secondary" for Buttons. So following this [example](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-styled-components-api) from the docs, I made this CustomButton component:

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

// const random = "just some random thing"

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: (props) => theme.palette[props.color].main,
    height: 48,
    padding: "0 30px",
    margin: 8,
  },
}));

const CustomButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { color, ...other } = props;
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <Button ref={ref} className={classes.root} {...other} />;
})

CustomButton.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.oneOf(["blue", "red"]).isRequired,
};

export default CustomButton
```

here is my `theme.js`:

```js
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { red } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#fff',
      contrastText: "#494949"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#f1f1f1',
    },
    red: {
      main: "#FF5E58",
    },
    green: {
      main: "#009A2B"
    },
    blue: {
      main: "#0082FF"
    },
    yellow: {
      main: "#FFB800"
    }
    
  },
  mixins: {
    toolbar: {
      minHeight: 70
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        html: {
          "scroll-behavior": "smooth"
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

In my Layout file where the Appbar is located I have a `NAV_ITEMS` object which I am looping through:

```js
const NAV_ITEMS = [
  {
    title: "About",
    link: "/about",
    color: "red",
  },
  {
    title: "Projects",
    link: "/projects",
    color: "yellow",
  },
  {
    title: "Toolbox",
    link: "/toolbox",
    color: "green",
  },
  {
    title: "Events",
    link: "/events",
    color: "blue",
  },
  {
    title: "Textbook",
    link: "/textbook",
    color: "red",
  },
  {
    title: "Login",
    link: "/login",
    color: "yellow",
  },
  {
    title: "Random",
    link: "/random",
    color: "blue",
  },
];
```

```js
 {NAV_ITEMS.map((item) => (
                <Link href={item.link} key={item.title} passHref>
                  <CustomButton color={item.color}>{item.title}</CustomButton>
                </Link>
              ))}
```

Now I am facing a weird bug where whenever I save a file while running "npm run dev", I see the correctly rendered Buttons, but when I refresh the page, the colors are all wrong and I get the following console error:

```
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text makeStyles-root-27 makeStyles-root-28" Client: "MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text makeStyles-root-27 makeStyles-root-29"
```

Here is a screenrecord of the error:

[image]

I am guessing the error is happening because of a mismatch between server-side rendered styles and client-side rendered styles, as you can see two different makeStyles on each element:

```html
<a class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text makeStyles-root-27 makeStyles-root-32" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" href="/textbook"><span class="MuiButton-label">Textbook</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></a>
```

How could I make this prop-based styling work on Next JS?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, which I was able to solve using the two solutions mentioned on the page below:

[Material UI + Nextjs: Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877230/material-ui-nextjs-drawer)

1: Prefix your style names

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  //...
}), {
  name: "MuiCustomStyle"
});
```

2: Use dynamic import with no SSR

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

export const ComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('./Component'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

That's it.